# Problema ciclo For

Tags: c++, bucle-for

Debo generar un programa con una funcion y el for, y mostrar el nombre del usuario, pero solo me permite una vez ingresar el primer nombre y se acaba el programa..

```
`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char nom()
{
    char nombre;
    cout<<"Nombre del usuario:" <<endl;
    cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"El Nombre del usuario es:"<<nombre<<endl;
}


main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5;)
        {
            nom();      
        }
}`
```

Comment: ¿Cómo es posible que no tengas un error? A la función `main` le falta el tipo de retorno que puede ser `void` o `int`. Otra cosa que te falta es la sección de incremento del `for`.  Puedes dejarlo vacío pero obtendrás un bucle infinito.

Comment: Ah el incremento fue un error si lo tenia jaja, aun con el int en main no me permite escribir los otros nombre mas que el del primero y termina el programa :/

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Cuando defines una variable tipo char si no lo haces en forma de arreglo significa que solo vas a tener un caracter, es decir, donde pones `char nombre;` estas definiendo una variable "nombre" de un solo caracter.

Lo que necesitas es utilizar un arreglo o cadena de caracteres `char nombre[10]` por ejemplo. En este caso estas creando un arreglo de 10 caracteres

Ten en cuenta que las cadenas de caracteres siempre deben terminar con el caracter nulo para indicar que el texto finaliza por lo que si defines `char nombre[10]` puedes almacenar 9 caracteres mas el caracter nulo que indica el final de la cadena

Si agregas eso a tu código entonces ya funciona

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char nom()
{
    char nombre[10];
    cout<<"Nombre del usuario:" <<endl;
    cin>>nombre;
    cout<<"El Nombre del usuario es:"<<nombre<<endl;
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            nom();      
        }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que también agregué `int` al main y el incremento en el "for" `i++`

Una cosa más, en tu función `nom()` te hace falta el `return`, si no deseas usar return entonces debe ser una función tipo `void`

Comment: `return true` en una función que dice devolver un `char`? No tiene ningún sentido, pero ... ¿Eso compila?

Comment: Si compila... si la función no es void requiere un return. A pesar de ser char si el usuario solo desea indicar que terminó, con el true basta

Comment: Basta ... pero porque es una conversión implícita que está descrita en el estándar ... no porque al compilador le de igual lo que estés retornando. En este caso has tenido esa suerte, pero no porque el compilador se lo trague es algo que se deba hacer, es una práctica que suele enmascarar problemas en multitud de ocasiones

Comment: en sí hace un cast de bool a char, como char es, de cierta manera, un entero, lo interpreta el compilador como 1, que casteado sería algo como ☺, es incorrecto y hay una mejor solución pero no es para cagarlo por intentar aportar.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, la función `nom` no debe devolver ningún valor, por lo que su declaración es incorrecta:

```
void nom()
{
    // ...
}
```

Ahora, en dicha función esperas leer un nombre, es decir, una cadena de caracteres. En C++ las cadenas de caracteres se suelen manejar con objetos tipo `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

void nom()
{
    string nombre;

    cout << "Nombre del usuario:\n";
    cin >> nombre;
    cout << "El nombre de usuario es: " << nombre << '\n';
}
```

Y para terminar, vamos con el `main`.

El bucle `for` se compone de tres partes:

```
for([INICIALIZACION]; [CONDICIONAL]; [INCREMENTOS])
```

En tu caso no estás incluyendo nada en los incrementos ni estás incrementando el valor de `i` en ningún sitio, luego el bucle se repetirá **infinitas veces**

Ya de paso, nota que es posible declarar la variable `i` dentro del bucle. Esta práctica tiene sus ventajas, ya que reduces la vida de la variable al propio bucle y eso evita usos incorrectos de dicha variable. Si necesitas otra variable `i` podrás crearla cuando la necesites, así que no hay penalizaciones al respecto:

```
for( int i=0; i<5; i++)
```

Comment: El tipo de retorno de la función `nom` no tiene por qué ser incorrecto. En su mente quizás pensaba retornar `nombre`. Quizás deberías decir algo como: "Ya que no estás devolviendo nada, cambia el tipo a `void`" o ya que no queda clara su intención: "Supondré que querías devolver `nombre` así que puedes hacerlo así". Un pequeño detalle, tu código no funcionaría sin `using namespace std`. Ambos sabemos de eso pero puede haber alguien que no.

Comment: @Mateo lee la pregunta, solo le piden imprimir un nombre, no que esa función retorne nada. Por otro lado, lo que comentas de `using namespace` es cierto, pero da la casualidad que en su código **sí existe** ese `using namespace`. Si revisas otras respuestas mías suelo ponerlo completo... pero hoy me ha dado por _innovar_ :)

Comment: Ah bien, lo mencionaba por si a caso.